# How to separate subscript and superscript in LaTeX?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I have a variable with a subscript describer `P_{\rm 1S}` I'd like to square it.

First a style question: is `(P_{\rm 1S})^2` or `P_{\rm 1S}^2` better? The programming part of the problem is that the latter aligns the superscript vertically above the subscript, I would like the power to be aligned further to the right distinct from the variable and its descriptors. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: in this case, the answer given is good.  but there are also situations (tensor notation, i believe) where a string of scripts must be "separated", as `x^a{}_b{}^c`.  (please take this as a model, not an actual case.)

Comment: At any rate, don't use `\rm`, use `\text{}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$(P_{\rm 1S})^2$` (which is the most precise) you can also write `${P_{\rm 1S}}^2$` (which should be also clear). However, as it is mentioned by egreg, `P_\mathrm{1S}` is better than `P_{\rm 1S}`, as `\rm` is obsolete in LaTeX2epsilon.

Comment: Also `P_\mathrm{1S}`, please.